# Getting null ObjectID from MongoDB using findByID in javascript - newbie

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am new to javascript and mongo and trying to find a course in my MongoDB database collection using id but getting null. Could you please help me with this?

**Note:** I am using MacBook. This is a very basic thing I am trying to do. I am able to fetch the object using .find() but findByID(id) doesn't seem to work for me. What am I missing? Let me know if any more detail is required.

**Edit:** A weird observation, refer the **image**. For the first one, I cannot find it or update it using id but I could find and update the second one. The first one was inserted in database using json file and second one was inserted using .save() in javascript.

**PFB my code:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercise', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to mongo-exercise database.'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Could not connect to mongo-exercise database.', err));

// Create the schema
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    price: Number,
    tags: [String],
    isPublished: Boolean
});

// Call the schema
const Course = mongoose.model('course', schema);

async function updateCourse(id) {
    try {
        const course = await Course
            .findById(id);
        console.log('Course is ', course);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Solution failed: ', err.message);
        throw error
    }
}

updateCourse("5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd");
```

[[image]]

Comment: MongoDB _id fields are usually type ObjectId, not string.  Try `updateCourse(ObjectId("5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd"));`

Comment: @Joe : `. findById()` takes in a string & internally it does convert `string` to `ObjectId()` prior to querying DB..

Comment: That is good to know! So I've been wasting the effort to convert all this time.

Comment: @Joe : Yes, it's a wrapper func provided by mongoose, useful when you're querying only with `_id`..

Comment: Thank you Joe and whoami for responding. Please refer my edit section also and help me understand and resolve this problem.

Comment: @Vers : If your `_id` field in database is of type `ObjectId()` then use `.findById()` else if your `_id` field is type string in database then use `.findOne({_id : someInputString})` but you need to remember that type of input should match with type of `_id` field in DB. Also do not maintain `_id` in two different types in DB either maintain it as string or `ObjectId()` for all the docs, I would say to maintain it as `ObjectId()` - let MongoDB create it for docs when they got inserted..

Comment: @whoami Thank u, although I did try with different functions like findOne() and others also, I will again try today and update. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me.when importing using compass, just deselect the _Id property as its a string. When imported mongodb driver will put in a new object _id with and objectid that can be queried.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. What you suggested was correct but it still doesn't let me find by id :(